# Inheritance container of Parent type cannot hold children?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, casting

I have a parent Menu class and children MainMenu, SettingsMenu, PauseMenu, etc.

I want to be able to hold them all in a vector...

I can do

```
std::vector<Menu*> myVector;
```

and then typecast each one when I push_back in the vector

```
pMainMenu = new MainMenu;
myVector.push_back((Menu*)pMainMenu);
```

and it compiles but something's not working right down the road...

It doesn't have to be a vector but I want to be able to iterate through them.

I'm always trying to implement the Observer pattern and I'm having difficulties with inheritance as well in that area!

---

For the Observer pattern I have an Observer class and Game inherits Observer. I have a Subject class inherited by InputComponent. Subject has a vector of Observer* called vObserver and a function called addObserver(Observer* observer) and adds the passed pointer in vObserver. I also have a function called Notify(event e), which iterates through vObserver and calls their onNotify functions.

So in Game, I have an InputComponent instance called inputComp. I do inputComp.addObserver(this) and inputComp.vObserver.size() is 1. Good. I have a call to Notify in InputComponent which does get triggered, but when it executes, the vObserver.size inside Subject is 0... idk what I'm doing wrong

EDIT:

```
class Menu
{
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual void onMouseMove(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual void onMouseButton(int button, bool is_down) = 0;
    friend class InputComponent;
    friend class MainMenuInputComponent;
protected:
    SDL_Renderer* _renderer;
    std::vector<Button> vButton;
    std::vector<SDL_Texture *> vTexture;
};

class MainMenu :  public Menu
{
public:
    MainMenu(SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    virtual void draw();
    virtual void onMouseMove(int x, int y);
    virtual void onMouseButton(int button, bool is_down);
    friend class MainMenuInputComponent;
};



class InputComponent: public Subject
{
public:
    virtual void processInput()
    {}
    static bool isMouseWithin(int mouseX, int mouseY, SDL_Rect rect)
    {
        if (mouseX >= rect.x && mouseX <= rect.x + rect.w && mouseY >= rect.y && mouseY <= rect.y + rect.h)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

class MainMenuInputComponent : public InputComponent
{
public:
    MainMenuInputComponent(MainMenu* owner)
        :_owner(owner){}
    virtual void processInput();
    virtual void onBtnClick(std::string btnName);

    MainMenu* _owner;
};

class Game : public Observer
{
public:

Game();
void initSDL();
void initGame();
void processGameInput();
void renderGame();
void update();
virtual void onNotify(Events e);

SDL_Window* myWindow;
SDL_Renderer* myRenderer;
std::vector<MainMenuInputComponent> vInputComponent;
std::stack<MainMenu*> menuStack;
};


Game::Game()
{
    initSDL();
    initGame();
}

void Game::initGame()
{
    //Create the Main Menu
    MainMenu* pMainMenu = new MainMenu(myRenderer);
    //Add menu to the stack
    menuStack.push((pMainMenu));
        //Add it's components to respective arrays
    MainMenuInputComponent inputComp = MainMenuInputComponent(pMainMenu);
    vInputComponent.push_back(inputComp);
        //Add Observer/Subject relationship.
    inputComp.addObserver((Observer*)this);
    int bob = (int)inputComp.vObserver.size(); //to see if size went up


}

void Game::processGameInput()
{
    if (!menuStack.empty())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)vInputComponent.size(); i++)
        {
            //Menu* compOwner = (Menu*)(vInputComponent[i]._owner);
            //std::unique_ptr<Menu, std::default_delete<Menu>> a = menuStack.top();
            if ((vInputComponent[i]._owner) == menuStack.top())
            {
                vInputComponent[i].processInput();
            }
            //vInputComponent[i].processInput();
        }
    }
    else
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)vInputComponent.size(); i++)
    {
        vInputComponent[i].processInput();
    }
}

void Game::renderGame()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(myRenderer);
    MainMenu* bob = menuStack.top();
    if (!menuStack.empty())
        (menuStack.top())->draw();
    SDL_RenderPresent(myRenderer);
}

void Game::onNotify(Events event)
{
    switch (event)
    {
    case POP_MENU:
        menuStack.pop();
        break;
    case GOTO_SETTINGS:
        //Menu* pSettingsMenu =(Menu*)(new SettingsMenu(myRenderer));
        //menuStack.push(std::unique_ptr<Menu>(pSettingsMenu));
        break;
        // Handle other events, and update heroIsOnBridge_...
    }
}

class Subject
{
public:
    void addObserver(Observer* observer)
    {
        vObserver.push_back(observer);
    }

    void removeObserver(Observer* observer)
    {
        //vObserver.erase(std::find(vObserver.begin(), vObserver.end(), 8));
    }


    std::vector<Observer*> vObserver;
protected:
    void notify(Events e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)vObserver.size(); i++)
        {
            vObserver[i]->onNotify(e);
        }
    }
};

class Observer
{
public:
    virtual ~Observer() {}

    virtual void onNotify(Events e) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Are you a victim of [sliced objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)?

Comment: yes something like that... and when I did std::vector<MainMenu> it worked but that's stupid because I wont have more than one MainMenu...! what to do?

Comment: _@user1420563_ Please don't try to improve your post with additional comments. Just place a horizontal bar and add this information to your question.

Comment: @user1420563: I'm sorry, but you need to create [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. It's a very good thing that you have provided code snippets, but as written they will not even compile, so I can't observe the behavior you see. If you want to others to help, you need to narrow down your problem to a few hundred lines at the most.

Comment: Ok I'm working on it, trying not to put too much code but their all related

Comment: anything new? I'm still stuck I don't know what else to try

Answer (score 1):

If `MainMenu` publically inherits from `Menu`, then you shouldn't even need to type cast the pointer to `MainMenu` to `Menu` at all. That is, this should work:

```
class Menu {};
class MainMenu : public Menu {};

std::vector<Menu*> myVector;
MainMenu* pMainMenu = // ...
myVector.push_back(pMainMenu);
```

However, what you really should be doing is using something like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`. Here's a more complete example, using `shared_ptr`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Menu
{
public:
    virtual void on_event() = 0;
    // virtual destructor needed for polymorphic base classes
    virtual ~Menu() {}
};

class MainMenu : public Menu
{
public:
    virtual void on_event()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world! from MainMenu" << std::endl;
    }
};

class PauseMenu : public Menu
{
public:
    virtual void on_event()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world! from PauseMenu" << std::endl;
    }
};

class SettingsMenu : public Menu
{
public:
    virtual void on_event()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world! from SettingsMenu" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Menu>> myVector;
    myVector.push_back(std::make_shared<MainMenu>());
    myVector.push_back(std::make_shared<PauseMenu>());
    myVector.push_back(std::make_shared<SettingsMenu>());
    for(auto& menu : myVector) {
        menu->on_event();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Hello world! from MainMenu
Hello world! from PauseMenu
Hello world! from SettingsMenu
```

This should also work and gives you the bonus feature of taking care of memory management for you.

Comment: I was using unique_ptr, and in fact the different Menus are in a stack, but for some reason when I did myStack.top()->functionCall() it gave me a wierd memory error.
I tried to se what exactly was myStack.top(), so I created a varible and assigned it to that variable so that I can look at it's value in the debugger, but it said something along the lines that I was trying to access a deleted function or something.
So I just used normal pointers and it got rid of that

Comment: @user1420563: If your `Menu`s are on the stack, then why did you have `pMainMenu = new MainMenu;` in your question? Can you update your question to reflect what you actually have? By default, `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` will handle your pointers as though they point to dynamic storage, not to stack objects, which might explain why you're seeing errors.

Comment: ok I my code I hope that'll be enough let me know if you want more